# How to modify pipe to remove duplicate entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have the following JSON File: http://pastebin.com/1TguvZXc

The duplicate 'body' can be found in the array by traversing through the array:

```
models[x].years[y].styles[z].submodel.body
```

In other words:

```
 models[0].years[0].styles[0].submodel.body
```

should be checked for duplicates in:

```
models[0].years[0].styles[1].submodel.body  
models[0].years[0].styles[2].submodel.body  
models[0].years[0].styles[n].submodel.body
```

The rest of the data is useless for me.

I have the following pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByCategory'
})
export class FilterByCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: any , search: string): any[] {
    if (input === undefined || input.length === 0) {
      return input;
    }

    const filteredArr: Array<any> = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));

    for (const model of filteredArr) {
      for (const year of model.years) {
        year.styles = year.styles.filter(style => {
          return style.submodel.body === search;
        });
        }
      }


    return filteredArr;
  }

}
```

How would I add an additional 'test' to my .filter function that checks if the value of 'submodel.body' exists in any of the styles array?

Comment: you can make use of `Array` `indexOf` or `includes` method. Check the browser compatibility for `includes`

Comment: I'm relatively new to javascript, can you elaborate where I would place this method in order to filter the results of `year.styles = year.styles.filter(style => {
          return style.submodel.body === search;
        });` ?

Comment: I suggest, you create a new array to store the `styles` and then check for the existence of style in the created array.

Comment: @Agalo create a new array to store the styles? They're already in arrays of style objects (which is what I need)

Comment: Do you want to have unique elements in the `year.styles` array ?

Comment: @Agalo yes, see the JSON file I included.
year.styles are indeed unique, however, since I don't care about the styles, I only care about the uniqueness of 'styles.submodel.body' --> note that even though MOST styles share the same styles.submodel.body, often enough, they have different styles.submodel.body

Comment: @Alago, misunderstood your question. Essentially, yes. if styles[0] has body = 'Coupe', and styles[1] has the same body, I would prefer styles[1] to be removed from the array (or conversely, since styles[0] already has body 'coupe', styles[1] is not added to new array)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135403/discussion-between-miguel-and-agalo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to use the `filter` function to remove the duplicate elements.

So, the function which removes duplicate would look like below and uses the `indexOf` function

```
function removeDuplicate(element, index, array) {
                return array.map(style => style.submodel.body).indexOf(element.submodel.body) === index;
            }
```

Following is working JS version of the code, you can make use of it and add the where condition for the **search** as defined in your post.

```js
function removeDuplicate(element, index, array) {
            return array.map(style => style.submodel.body).indexOf(element.submodel.body) === index;
        }

var data = '{"models":[{"id":"Acura_ILX","name":"ILX","niceName":"ilx","years":[{"id":401640361,"year":2017,"styles":[{"id":401640368,"name":"AcuraWatch Plus Package 4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"AcuraWatch Plus Package"},{"id":401640367,"name":"Technology Plus and A-SPEC Packages 4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"Technology Plus and A-SPEC Packages"},{"id":401640366,"name":"Premium Package 4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"Premium Package"},{"id":401640365,"name":"Premium and A-SPEC Packages 4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"Premium and A-SPEC Packages"},{"id":401640364,"name":"Technology Plus Package 4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"Technology Plus Package"},{"id":401640363,"name":"4dr Sedan (2.4L 4cyl 8AM)","submodel":{"body":"Sedan","modelName":"ILX Sedan","niceName":"sedan"},"trim":"Base"}]}]},{"id":"Acura_NSX","name":"NSX","niceName":"nsx","years":[{"id":200779937,"year":2017,"styles":[{"id":101418796,"name":"2dr Coupe AWD (3.5L 6cyl Turbo gas/electric hybrid 9AM)","submodel":{"body":"Coupe","modelName":"NSX Coupe","niceName":"coupe"},"trim":"Base"}]}]}],"modelsCount":6}';


var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
jsonData.models.forEach(model => 
                         model.years.forEach(year => 
   year.styles = year.styles.filter(removeDuplicate)  
   ));
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Will apply and respond with any troubles. Thanks! @Agalo